# How Can I plot or show specific Columns in a CSV File?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I got this CSV File and it look like this:

```
       Country/Region  Confirmed   Deaths   Recovered   
0       Andorra            862        54        803
1       Angola             452        24        124
         ...
```

The CSV File is in a alphabetical order.

Here is my Code how to try select specific Columns:

```
csv_df = pd.read_csv(adsf.csv)
csv.head()
csv_df.loc[csv_df["Country/Region"] == "China"]
```

> Here shows only the column "China"

```
Country/Region   Confirmed   Deaths   Recovered
 China            85246       4644      78228
```

But my Goal is to filter a specific amount of Country/Regions

It should look like this:

```
         Country/Region   Confirmed   Deaths   Recovered
32         China               85246     4644      78228
42         France              13743      321      13334
97         Spain               35311     2134       4532
```

These Numbers arent real. This is just an Exampel of Numbers.

Comment: Can you be more clear. Also please give an appropriate example with numbers so as to understand exactly what you want to achieve. This will help solve the problem much faster.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this,

- One way

```
csv_df = pd.read_csv("adsf.csv")
custom_df=csv_df[["column_name1","column_name2"]]
custom_df.head() # this show chosen columns
```

- Another way

```
csv_df=pd.read_csv("adsf.csv",usecols=["column_name1","column_name2"])
csv_df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ?

```
csv_df = pd.read_csv(adsf.csv) csv.head() 
filter_by_country = csv_df["Country/Region"] == "China"
filter_by_country.head()
```

The output should be filtered out by the country/region column.